# Why is my prototype cell background color not changing on the iPad simulator?

Tags: ios, tableview, cell, background-color

So I'm a little confused about why there would be any difference here..

I'm busy figuring out how to use split view controllers, and just messing around in my menu TableView.  I changed the background color of my prototype cell, which was reflected by the iphone 6+ sim.

But when running on an iPad, the background color is just plain white.  I don't understand what would cause this, since I'm just making the changes in the storyboard..?

Sorry for the image links, not enough reputation to post them inline (hopefully that'll change soon)

[image]

[image]

Note I am *NOT* running two simulators at once, that is a screenshot of two screenshots.

Comment: Are you changing the background color of the cell or contentView of the cell? My first guess would be to check there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the background color of the content view of your custom cell instead of background color of your cell.

Comment: I have the same problem and this does not solve it for me. In my case, both the cell AND the content view need to have a background of clearColor. Setting cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() in cellForRowAtIndexPath works, but it still doesn't address the underlying issue of why the unarchived cell would be different on iPhone versus iPad. Any ideas? I think this may also be leading to other bugs.